# Не работает кик в боте discord

Tags: discord.py

учусь делать бота для дискорда. Хотел реализовать функцию кика но при команде `!kick`ничего не происходит, даже никаких ошибок не появляется. Код бота прилагаю.

```
import random
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.all())


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(name='GTA V', type=1))


@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(768743908045488161)
    await channel.send(f'@everyone {member.mention} проходи не задерживайся!')


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(768743908045488161)
    await channel.send(f'@everyone {member.mention} покинул нас...')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!ДаНет'):
        a = random.randint(1, 2)
        if a == 1:
            await message.channel.send("Да!")
        else:
            await message.channel.send("Нет!")


@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason):
    await ctx.send("Изгоняем участника {0} по причине: {1}".format(member, reason))
    await member.kick(reason=f'{ctx.author} Выгнал {member}')


client.run('token')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Поясните, что Вы хотели получить, и что в результате работает не так.

Comment: При вводе команды !kick должен исключаться человек из сервера. Когда я прописываю эту команду ничего не происходит, даже никакой ошибки не появляется

Answer (score 0):

возможно проблема в наличии разрешения у бота, потому что у меня этот код работает
В коде разрешения можно прописать так:

```
discord.Intents.all()
```

стоит проверить, есть ли эти разрешения в кабинете бота на discord/developers и посмотреть на всякий права на сервере

также стоит немного изменить команду:

```
@bot.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason = None):
    if reason:
        await ctx.send("Изгоняем участника {0} по причине: {1}".format(member, reason))
        await member.kick(reason=f'{ctx.author} Выгнал {member}')
    else:
        await ctx.send("Изгоняем участника {0}".format(member))
        await member.kick()
```